# Render objects with vertices and normals

Tags: opengl, rendering

What's the easiest way to render objects with vertices and normals of the object given?

Answer (score 0):

Draw the vertices (point, normal, colour), then draw the vertices + normal (assuming normal is unit length, point + normal, normal, colour) and give it a colour.

For normal mapping, colour RGB = normal XYZ * 0.5 + (0.5, 0.5, 0.5).

The half and then add (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) is effectively scaling it and placing its direction within the +ve quadrant. There should be no negative values for the colour components.